# Index of a subgroup is preserved under group isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $\varphi : G\to G'$ be a group isomorphism and let $N\lt G$.

> prove: if $[G:N]\lt \infty$ then $[G:N]=[G':\varphi(N)]$

It is known that $\varphi(N)$ is indeed a subgroup of $G'$,

but how can I show equality of indices?

Note: I have yet to learn any isomorphism theorems.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is the definition of index you are using? Because there are various approaches, and depending on the definition you are using one fits better than the other.

Comment: Index is defined as the number of lest or right cosets

Comment: Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism, what does this tell you about the dimension of the image $\varphi(N)$?

Comment: Perfect: then take each and every coset of $N$ in $G$ and map it to $G'$ using $\varphi$. Doing so will result in cosets of $\varphi(N)$.

Comment: @b00nheT Out of pure curiosity, what other definitions of index are there?

Comment: @jgon I know of only one, but I cannot exclude that there can be more than one.

Comment: @b00nheT Completely reasonable, I was just curious, since I also only knew of one.

Comment: An obvious second definition for finite $G$ would be $[G:N]:=|G|/|N|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $gN$ be a left coset for $g\in G$. Then, since $\varphi$ is a group homomorphism, if you take $n\in N$, then $\varphi(gn)=\varphi(g)\varphi(n)$, so clearly $\varphi(gN)\subseteq\varphi(g)\varphi(N)$. Since $\varphi$ is surjective, one has that every left coset of $G'$ is of the form $\varphi(g)\varphi(N)$.

Injectivity gives us that no two distinct cosets $g'N$ and $gN$ map to the same $\varphi(g)\varphi(N)$, since if $\varphi(g')\varphi(N)=\varphi(g)\varphi(N)$, then for some $n,n'\in N$

$\varphi(g')\varphi(n')=\varphi(g)\varphi(n).$

But this is the same as saying $g'n'=gn$, so $g'N=gN$.

Puting all together one concludes that the number of left cosets are the same.